# Chrome Extension: Javascript injected from Background.js to tab keeps running even if tab reloads. How to make injected javascript run only once?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my extension I am creating a new tab with a url from `background.js` script. And on page loading completion I am inserting a Javascript file named `addAlias.js` to that tab which will perform some tasks and click a submit button.

The problem is that after submit button is clicked the page in tab changes but the injected scripts starts running again.

I want to run it only one time when tab is created for first time.

Here is my code:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name":"Extension Name",
    "description":"This extension description",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "icons":{"128":"icon_128.png"},
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon":"icon.png",
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "permissions":["activeTab", "background", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tabs){
  chrome.tabs.create({url : tabURL}, function(tab){
    addPageCompleteListener(tab); //Passing tab to add listener if the tab loading completed or not.
  });
});

function addPageCompleteListener(tabOpened){
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tabId==tabOpened.id){
      if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        // It means Page has completely loaded
        //Now injecting Js script file
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabOpened.id, {file: 'addAlias.js'});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{code:'console.log("addAlias.js loaded");'})
      }
    }
    });
}
```

addAlias.js

```
//Some other code
let add_alias_btn = document.getElementById('SubmitYes'); //Selecting submit button
/*
Some tasks
*/
add_alias_btn.click(); //Clicking the submit button
```

Comment: Do you load background.js in popup.html?

Comment: @wOxxOm No I just send a Message from popup.js to background.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a new `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener to inject the content script and, therefore, the script is injected again every time the tab is updated. Try this in your background script to inject the content script only once after the tab is created:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: tabURL}, function(tab){
    //by default, content scripts are loaded after page has finished loading
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'addAlias.js'}, function(){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:'console.log("addAlias.js loaded");'});
    });
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that addAlias.js is not declared as content scripts in my manifest file. So even if a file is not a content script it is loaded after page has finished loading?

Comment: @Abhay Yes, according to the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) and [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time), by default content scripts run after `window.onload` has fired.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation reference!